# Allow all domains when adding a new user to Azure B2C using the microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am creating user with **gmail, Facebook and any business account** with azure ad. It will not create a new account with this domain. It uses a its custom domain for create account that we created in azure costum domain .

> The domain portion of the userPrincipalName property is invalid. You must use one of the verified domain names in your organization.

My login feature is independent of domain, so how can this be resolved?

Comment: Hello @Mradul, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> The domain portion of the userPrincipalName property is invalid. You
> must use one of the verified domain names in your organization.

You might get this type of error when you added your custom domain in Azure AD tenant, but you haven’t verified that domain yet. Would suggest you to please verified that custom domain in Azure AD by adding TXT records of your domain.

Please refer this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain#add-your-custom-domain-name-to-azure-ad) to know how to verified domain.

Coming to your next problem you can add your `Gmail` or `Facebook` users in Azure AD by sending them Invitation as well as a guest user.